# Need to get basic profile of other users in Linkedin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, linkedin-api

I need to get the basic profile of other users, for example if the user paste their public profile url and click go, it has to fetch their profile details.

I have followed this,

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Login-with-LinkedIn-Account-and-fetch-User-Profile-details-like-ID-Name-Picture-and-Email-in-ASPNet.aspx

But this gets my profile details, i want the other users profile details.
my scope is basic profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible getting an other user informations by using LinkedIn API. The user must authenticate the application by his or her username and password.

Comment: Is It possible using web scrapping with mechanize library python?